# MySQL Regexp error

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table `files` with rows as follows:

```
+-----+----------------------+----------+
| id  | file_path            | owner_id |
+-----+----------------------+----------+
| 332 | /path/to/file1/      |      150 |
| 333 | /path/to/file1file1/ |      150 |
| 334 | /path/to/file2/      |      151 |
| 335 | /path/to/file3/      |      152 |
| 336 | /path/to/file4/      |      150 |
| 337 | /path/to/file5/      |      150 |
| 338 | /path/to/file6/      |      151 |
+-----+----------------------+----------+
```

and using this MySQL query:

```
select * from files WHERE file_path REGEXP '(file1){1}';
```

Produces this:

```
+-----+----------------------+----------+
| id  | file_path            | owner_id |
+-----+----------------------+----------+
| 332 | /path/to/file1/      |      150 |
| 333 | /path/to/file1file1/ |      150 |
+-----+----------------------+----------+
```

But with my understanding, it should produce this:

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+
| id  | file_path       | owner_id |
+-----+-----------------+----------+
| 332 | /path/to/file1/ |      150 |
+-----+-----------------+----------+
```

What's wrong? How should I modify the query to produce wanted results? I want to get rows which contain string (file1) ONCE and ONCE only.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

```
+-----+-----------------------+----------+
| id  | file_path             | owner_id |
+-----+-----------------------+----------+
| 349 | /path/to/file1/       |      158 |
| 350 | /path/to/file1file1/  |      158 |
| 351 | /path/to/file1X/      |      158 |
| 352 | /path/to/file1Xfile1/ |      158 |
| 353 | /path/to/file2/       |      159 |
| 354 | /path/to/file3/       |      160 |
| 355 | /path/to/file4/       |      158 |
| 356 | /path/to/file5/       |      158 |
| 357 | /path/to/file6/       |      159 |
+-----+-----------------------+----------+
```

With this table I want to input `file1` and get `/path/to/file1/`, `file1X` and get `/path/to/file1X/` etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from files WHERE file_path REGEXP '(\/file1\/)';
```

This should work.Your regex wont work cause it says "pick line having `1 line1` which both lines satisfy.

EDIT:

use this

```
\/file1[^\/]*\/
```

to match `line1x`

Comment: `select * from files WHERE file_path REGEXP '(file1){1,1}';`

This produces the same result, but won't work correctly either - still produces 2 lines, shouldn't 1?

Comment: @deerdeer this wont work cause you do not have anchors `start` and `end`.So if anywhere in line it finds `line1` it will be a pass.

Comment: Yours works fine for now, but I want mine to be different when I enter more. Editing main post with more information. Thanks a lot for helping, though.

Comment: Alrighi, I've managed to make it work to my needs. Thanks a lot for help and explanations.

Comment: @deerdeer as per your latest example `\/file1[^\/]*\/` should work

Comment: Could you break it down? \ is an escape character from my understanding, what about the ^ and *?

It's perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @deerdeer `[^\/]*\/` here `[]` is a character class , `^` means do not include whats der in the class.so the regex will travel till it finds `\/`.